# Getting started with BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

I am a .NET developer and I have developed a software for an organization in which there are 2 other different software applications. All these 3 applications are isolated and they don't send and receive data to and from any other software.

The organization's manager asked me to integrate these products.

After some research on the internet I found that I have to use BizTalk. Now I have some basic knowledge about BizTalk (like what are Schema,Maps,Pipelines,Orchestration etc).

The problem is that I don't know the changes I have to make for my own software and the change I have to ask the other developers (of the other software) to make in their own software to be able to integrate them via BizTalk.

Shall we make web services for our software?

Is that possible to connect directly to databases? Is that a good practice at all?

Any other suggestion or resources will be very appreciated.

Comment: You don't "have to use BizTalk". BizTalk is just one of many options out there.   Does your organization already use BizTalk?  If so it makes a lot of sense to use it. However if don't already have then you may have to do a cost benefit analysis, including looking at what else you are going to do in the future e.g. are you going to be interfacing to other applications or external parties.

Comment: It doesn't use BizTalk but it is going to interfacing to other applications and external parties.

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to first have an indication on the licensing cost of BizTalk Server, especially if you wish a HA (High Available) environment, the initial cost for a company can be quite high.

This link can help you get an understanding: http://blogs.biztalk360.com/understand-biztalk-server-2013-licensing/

Answer (score 2):

Since this a very broad topic, I'll stick to answering your specific questions:

1. Sure, this is frequently called a Web Service Facade.  It's most useful when many different apps will be calling into it.
2. If you own the apps and their databases, yes, this is a perfectly valid solution.  BizTalk connects natively to SQL Server and Oracle as well as other databases through an ODBC Adpater.
3. You could also program your existing apps to emit and consume Xml messages.

Comment: Sorry if I answer this too late. but what I am really confused by this. which one of these solutions are best practice? and by sending and receiving Xml messages, do you mean I have to have a webservice to interact with Xml messages? can you suggest me any book, article etc to getting started with BizTalk and changes I have to make in my software to be able to connect to BizTalk?

Comment: The best practice is the one that works best for you though very often external factors will drive you to one solution path or another.  What type of interface is easier for you to create?  Web Services, Stored Procedures or Xml Messaging?  They would all provide near identical business functionality so go with the one that you or your organization is most comfortable with.  This is the book I would get: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-BizTalk-Server-2010-Unleashed/dp/0672331187/ref=sr_1_cc_1?s=aps&ie=UTF8&qid=1390056722&sr=1-1-catcorr&keywords=biztalk

Comment: I think Stored Procedures and Web Service are better choices. you know after lot of research now I am a little familiar with BizTalk. but the problem is I need some walkthrough tutorials for different adapters. Like how can I work with SQL adapter or WCF adapter